# Dynamics CRM 2015 Duplicate Row Cleanup

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am working with Dynamics CRM 2015 online and have been given the task to remove duplicates from Active Accounts.

I am Currently Using Visual Studio 2012 SSIS with COZYROC SSIS+ package.

After pulling all the active accounts into the table ActiveAccounts(all 15000 accounts), I created the tables NormalNameOccurrences(Null at first) and  ActiveAccountsPossibleDuplicateReport(Null at First). At first I generated a separate column that assigned each account a normal name. The rules for the normal name are:

- No Spaces
- No Alphanumeric Characters
- '&' signs are replaced with 'and'
- Corporation, Incorporated, and Company are abbreviated (Corp, Inc, Co)

After this was done I ran this statement to find all of the occurrences that had a count greater than 1 based off the first 10 characters

```
INSERT INTO NormalNameOccurrences 
select LEFT(NormalName, 10) AS NormalName,COUNT(*) AS Occurrences
FROM ActiveAccounts
GROUP BY LEFT(NormalName, 10) 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY NormalName
```

Then I ran the following Query to group the accounts on the first 10 characters

```
INSERT INTO ActiveAccountsPossibleDuplicateReport

SELECT
    DupeGroupID.*,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LEFT(DupeGroupID.NormalName,10)) as Match_ID

FROM
(
       SELECT *
       FROM  ActiveAccounts a
       WHERE EXISTS 
      (
        SELECT * 
        FROM NormalNameOccurences 
        Where LEFT(a.NormalName,10) = NormalName
       )
) DupeGroupID
```

This is an example of what it puts out

```
Accountid   Name                           NormalName           Match_ID
1165894512  AT and T                       ATandT                   1
1236549458  AT&T                           ATandT                   1
9764312456  AT & T                         ATandT                   1
9856225415  Furniture                      FurnitureIndustry        2
6565652626  Furniture Inc.                 FurnitureIndustryInc     2
6427346857  Chemical Engineers of Idaho    ChemicalEngineersofIdaho 3
6457948461  Chemical Entourage, Inc.       ChemicalEntourageInc     3
5544997761  Chemical Entry, LLC            ChemicalEntryLLC         3
```

My problem is when I Run this query it results in a handful of false positives. Account Names might start with the same 10 characters but the next characters do not match at all.
On the Other side, If I try and increase the character look-up to say 12 instead of 10, I lose a lot of accounts that are the same account however one of the Account names contains a account type such as the example above with account 9856225415 and 6565652626.

Any advice on how to work around this would be much appreciated!

Comment: I doubt you can make anything 100% bulletproof, but have you considered using a levenshtein difference instead? It sounds like it would be perfect for this purpose. I know there are implentations in mysql, though it might be easier to do "outside" - ie. In visual studio in your case (I have nothing to offer in that department)

Comment: Note i removed mysql tag, added sql tag, and changed title

Comment: Check out the fuzzy grouping component in SSIS.  This is the tool for this exact purpose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141764.aspx.  MS uses there own algorithms for matching, but they work surprisingly well

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I tried Fuzzy grouping before but all that does is return the entire account table set with correlation values 0.0-1.0. What I am looking for is a process that will analyze all the accounts in my table and return a separate table that only contains the possible account duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to give SSIS fuzzy grouping another go if you need an automated way to identify duplicates.  Here is a great walk-through: http://ssis-tutorial-online.blogspot.com/2013/04/fuzzy-grouping-transformation.html

By trial and error, you can figure out what similarity threshold gives you a dataset with the least amount of errors.  The output key column will help you identify groups.  Then you are left with the task of aggregating that into a single record.  i.e. what will the ultimate normal name be and all the other attributes.  It is often best to deduplicate on a few different vectors, like include zip code and email, for example.

If you wish to consider a manual approach DQS has a matching process and the MDS plugin for excel includes a way for de-duping records.  Sometimes it is much better to let the SMEs clean up the mess.